# Oracle Uniface - selected data too large for SQL Workbench

Tags: oracle, uniface

I am currently working on a stupid system where I have given no direct DB access but a weird SQL Workbench which can not do most of the things apart from some basic stuff. So for some reason I need to do a SELECT * on one of the tables which have 174 columns. And whenever I try that it gives me the following error:

> "ERROR: Error -27 was encountered whilst running the SQL command. (-3)
>   Error -3 running SQL : ORACLE Driver Error [-27]: Selected data too
>   large for SQL Workbench"

Quick googling gave me nothing apart from (in one of the oracle documents):

> In the SQL Editor, the maximum length of one row of the formatted
>   result is 8190 bytes. When this length is exceeded, the ORA connector
>   generates the above error

Now, I was wondering if anyone could give me a solution that would be a great help. One of the solution I am thinking is to increase the Maximum Length for Ora Connector/Driver. But I am novice in Oracle and do not know anything apart from querying. So haven't been able to change the Maximum Length yet.

So, please if anybody could help me out with this, that would be great.

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

Being asked to do database work trough the Uniface SQL Workbench is not a good situation. It is only a very simple thing that you can use in an emergency if nothing else is available.

You could run a couple of queries, each time with the primary key and a bunch of fields and stitch the result together in Excel.

If you have access to the Uniface Development Environment you can use it to convert your Oracle data to, for example, XML. Instructions are in the Uniface helpfile ulibrary.chm, see command line switch /cpy.

You cannot change the maximum record length of the Uniface Oracle Connector.

Comment: I dont think xml is gonna help me as i said there are 174 columns in that table and i need all of them. But thanks and i will give it a go when i go to work tomorrow